# How to calculate rotation based on two pointer events

Tags: javascript, multi-touch, pointer-events

I have problems with a multitouch library, in this case Interact.js, which e.g. generates a pinch / rotate for a target although one of the two pointer events is outside the target when the gesture is started. That doesn't do me any good.

I wonder if it makes sense to rely on a library or to create the 2 gestures, drag and rotate, myself.

In order not to start all over, there is an example for this, i.e. to determine the mathematics of the rotation from the movement of 2 points, I have managed the relevant pointers so far.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: the angle between two points is `Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1)`

Comment: you are absolutely right, the movement during the pinch rotate is easy, sometimes it just has to be done. how could i mess around with immature multitouch plugins for vuejs for days. with a physics animation it already looks pretty cool.